# Using JMeter to test Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: web-services, soap, dynamics-crm-2011, jmeter, performance-testing

I am using JMeter to make test calls to Dynamics CRM 2011 web services.

I have a SOAP/XML-RPC Request configured to call the Retrieve operation. The **URL** is set to http://<>/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc/web and the **SOAPAction** is set to Retrieve.

When I run the test, I get 401 (Unauthorized) error.

I tried adding an HTTP Authorization Manager with the username and password as well but still no joy.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're using BASIC_DIGEST and enter the base domain name in the realm and the domain of your user.

--Example--

Base URL: <- Leave This Blank

Username: SomeUserName

Password: Your Password

Domain:   CONTOSO

Realm:    CONTOSO.LOCAL (Or .com .org or however you have your domain configured)

Mechanism: BASIC_DIGEST